# char array compilation error

Tags: c++

What is the problem in my code? It does not compile..

```
   class FileNames
   {
        public:
           static char* dir;
           static char name[100];

           static void Init3D()
           {
            FileNames::dir = "C://3D//";
            FileNames::name = "abc";
           }
   };
```

Comment: Next time, please post the compilation errors you are getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array, so `FileNames::name = "abc"` fails (`char arr[4] = "abc"` works, however, because this is a direct initialization, not assignment). Either use a `char*` here as well, or use `strcpy` to copy data to the array or better a `std::string` which avoids many of the downsides of raw strings.

Most importantly you need to define your static members somewhere at global scope, outside a function:
`char FileNames::name[100];`. At this time initialization syntax using `=` would be possible even with the array, but the string to be assigned needs to have the same length as the array.

Comment: You must mean FileNames::name fails -- not FileNames::dir. FileNames::dir is not an array

Comment: Thanks, fixed that and clarified.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1) You've duplicated the variable `name` (with two different types).
2) You can't initialise static members like that (see example below).

The last thing isn't a problem as such, but you should consider using `std::string` instead, as that encapsulates string functionality so that you don't need to deal with raw pointers. It's a lot less painful, especially if you're new to this sort of thing.

Change it to this:

```
// Header file
class FileNames
{
private:
    static char* name;
public:
    static char* dir;
};

CPP file
#include "FileNames.h"

char* FileNames::name = "abc";
char* FileNames::dir = "C://3D//";

// Now use your class...
```

Comment: 1) Umm... no he has not?  2) He isn't initializing, he is assigning values to them in runtime, which should be fine. The problem is, as pointed out in another answer, that you cannot copy arrays in C/C++ using the assignment operator.

Comment: @Lundin, 1) in the original version of his question he did (it was static char* name), which leads onto the reasons for 2).

Comment: Indeed, must have been in the first five minutes or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing like this:

```
class FileNames
{
    public:
       static char* dir;
       static char name[];

};   

char *FileNames::dir = "C://3D//";
char FileNames::name[100] = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to actually define the static members outside of the class?  Also, I don't believe you need to resolve the scope unless you're actually outside of the class.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
FileNames::dir = new char[strlen("C://3D//")];
strcpy(FileNames::dir, "C://3D//");
strcpy(FileNames::name, "abc");
```

Also, don't forget to `#include <cstring>` and to later `delete[](FileNames::dir)`

Comment: strcpy into the random address where dir points at is a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: @Lundin - Agreed! Blech... who would ever do that! :p